# Is my Big Oh proof correct?

Tags: asymptotics

I need pointers or corrections on my proof procedure.

Prove $x^2 + 2x + 1 \in O(x^2)$:

$x^2 + 2x + 1 \le cx^2$

$1+2/x+1/x^2 \le c$

This inequality holds for $x \ge 1$ and $c \ge 4$. Thus $x^2+2x+1 \in O(x^2)$

Comment: That's a Big O ("Big Oh"), not a Big Omega ("Big $\Omega$").  Also, your proof is just fine if you reverse the order of the lines.  So you should have $$\begin{align*}1 + 2/x + 1/x^2 \leq 4 \quad \forall x \geq 1 \qquad &\Longrightarrow \qquad x^2 + 2x + 1 \leq 4x^2 \quad \forall x \geq 1 \\ &\Longrightarrow \qquad |x^2 + 2x + 1| \leq 4 |x^2| \quad \forall x \geq 1\end{align*}$$ which implies that $x^2+2x+1 \in O(x^2)$ on the domain $x \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Big O is determined from the [#Formal_definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) or by using the limit superior. Your way of determining is not conventional and rather adhoc

**Formal definition of Big O**
$f(x) = O(g(x))$ $\iff$ there exists a positive real number M and a real number $x_0$ such that

$$|f(x)| \le M|g(x)| \forall x>x_0\tag1$$

So starting with your expression

$$|x^2 + 2x + 1|\le x^2 + 2x^2 + 1$$
$$\le x^2 + 2x^2 + x^2$$
$$\le 4x^2$$
$$\le 4|x^2|$$

So
$$|x^2 + 2x + 1|\le 4|x^2|$$

Co relating with $(1)$, we have 
$$|x^2 + 2x + 1|\le 4|x^2| \forall x>1$$
where $M=4, x_0 = 1$
So
$$f(x) = O(x^2), as\quad  x\quad \to\infty$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate where and why do you think my process falls short? I really did not get much from your answer.

Comment: @cRaZiRiCaN: I have added couple of lines to my answer for the reasoning of not supporting your approach